# Android: how to use mapbox setZoomControlsEnabled?

Tags: android, android-studio, mapbox, mapbox-android, android-studio-3.1.3

I just start today using mapbox for android. I want to display zoom control on mapbox mapview. I did a little research, the method should be setZoomControlsEnabled. but I dont know how to use this method on mapbox android sdk v6.3.0. the documentation pretty clear: https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/6.3.0/index.html?com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/UiSettings.html . But how I can use it?

another info about setZoomControlsEnabled, it should be a method of mapView class and can be called like this:

```
mapView.setZoomControlsEnabled
```

but I tried and it doesn't work. a github link as reference: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/2537

Comment: I dont understand why someone downvoted question like this. I guarantee no one can found a code example about this anywhere

Comment: You can find it here: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/search?q=setZoomControlsEnabled&type=

Comment: ok, thank you @P-Zenker

Comment: @P-Zenker Your link says "We couldn’t find any code matching setZoomControlsEnabled"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `MapboxMap` object get the reference to the `UiSettings`:

```
mapView.getMapAsync(mapboxMap -> {
  mapboxMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

or use the XML attributes:

```
<com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
    android:id="@id/mapView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:mapbox_uiZoomControls="true" />
```

Also, check out the [first steps](https://www.mapbox.com/help/first-steps-android-sdk/) and [docs](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/maps/overview/).

Comment: thank you.. it works. they should be add this code somewhere at the docs

Comment: `ZoomButtonsController` [deprecated](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/13197) in `v6.7.0` and [removed](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/pull/13198) in `v7.0.0`.